# How to make this method reusable?

Tags: c#, reusability

I have copy pasted this method into two classes. I would rather reuse it from the first class. This is in a windows forms application.

```
public void defineMapArea()
{
    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

    // Dock the PictureBox to the form and set its background to white.
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;

    // Connect the Paint event of the PictureBox to the event handler method.
    pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);

    // Add the PictureBox control to the Form. 
    this.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
}
```

The only thing that needs to change in the method from one class to another is the "this" keyword which refers to the class, as hovering over "this" confirms. I thought maybe "this" will just apply to the class calling the method, but i think it still refers to the class that the method is defined in. It would be fantastic to simply pass a class as a parameter, but i'm thinking that doesn't work as i have attempted that.

Any help appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You can add a parameter to the method like `defineMapArea(MyForm form)`, which is the "pass a class as a parameter" idea. What have you tried?

Comment: Please consider the answer @Thorsten Dittmar gave you. Is is the only one so far (the time is 11:56 AM GMT+3 on the 10th of september 2013) which correctly solves the `PaintEventHanlder` issue also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do so:

```
public static void DefineMapArea(Form form, Action<object, PaintEventArgs> handler)
{
    if (form == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("form");
    }

    if (handler == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("handler");
    }

    PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

    // Dock the PictureBox to the form and set its background to white.
    pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;

    // Connect the Paint event of the PictureBox to the event handler method.
    pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(handler);

    // Add the PictureBox control to the Form. 
    form.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
}
```

You can call it (assuming from your form):

```
DefineMapArea(this, (sender, e) =>
{
    // ... put here your code
});
```

Or

```
DefineMapArea(this, Handler);

void Handler(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // ... put here your code
}
```

Comment: why would go and presume he's using .NET 4.0 and do that `Action<object, PaintEventArgs>` thing when you already have `PaintEventHandler` to work with ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It works in .NET 3.5 also. In .NET 3.0 it doesn't, but on the other hand there's no `Action<T1, T2>` in 3.0. But on the other hand you don't know if the asking user isn't bound by legacy code to 3.0. My point was: since you **have** to make a cast to `PaintEventHandler` explicitly, why not simply use that particular type as your parameter type...

Comment: Thanks. I've got .NET 4.5. When calling this, is the form the class.ActiveForm, or can you just pass the class? Also, the action is a bit confusing to me. Could you do an example of calling it from a class?

Comment: Thanks. When i call it from another method with "this" keyword it says cannot be accessed with an instance reference, qualify it with a type name instead.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a helper class that looks like this:

```
public static class MapHelper
{
    public static void defineMapArea(this Control parent, PaintEventHandler handler)
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

        // Dock the PictureBox to the form and set its background to white.
        pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;

        // Connect the Paint event of the PictureBox to the event handler method.
        pictureBox1.Paint += handler;

        // Add the PictureBox control to the Form. 
        parent.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
parentControl.defineMapArea(new PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint));
```

This is an extension method that works on any control! Please note that you have to pass the `PaintEventHandler` as additional parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I got so many answers that i just used the one that didn't involve a new class, however this solution looks very good too. I'm considering this solution as i have never extended a control and it would show me how. Is the way you called it correct? It takes one argument because the parentControl is already stated as the first part of the calling code line?

Comment: That's how extension methods work. Please not the `this` keyword in the method declaration. Extension methods are more or less syntactic sugar. Internally, I guess the compiler translates this to `MapHelper.defineMapArea(parentControl, ...)` (and you could also call it that way), but the extension method approach blends in more nicely with the way you call methods on objects in C#. Please also note that extension methods work with all sorts of classes, not just `Control`. You could also extend `String` or `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

You may write like this:

```
class TestClass
{
    internal static void defineMapArea(Form1 form)
    {
        PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();

        // Dock the PictureBox to the form and set its background to white.
        pictureBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pictureBox1.BackColor = Color.White;

        // Connect the Paint event of the PictureBox to the event handler method.
        pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(form.pictureBox1_Paint);

        // Add the PictureBox control to the Form. 
        form.Controls.Add(pictureBox1);
    }
}
```

And can access from other class in this way:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TestClass.defineMapArea(this);
    }

    public void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Requires the `Paint` handler to be public :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can use form properties. Add the following to each form:

public Control clsThis
        { 
            get
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

then you can reference the control by using clsThis and send it to the method as a parameter